# Vertical alignment of an image in a Twitter Bootstrap cell (height is unknown)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap grid and I am trying to center an image (200x100 per example provided) inside a cell.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 container">
                <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a lot of techniques provided on internet without any luck. (BTW most of them explicitly define a height) As a proof I provide some of them here:

[Example1](https://plnkr.co/edit/f4Vke6nuXZzUNuLfMk9m?p=preview):  a trick with padding-top: 100% increases a row which I do not need.

[Example2](https://plnkr.co/edit/dfz5s8iFOvIVmERYPcaQ?p=preview):  table/table-cell just not working

Example 3:  a trick with inline-block and vertical align is not working

```
   <style>
        .container:before {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        img {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
```

Example 4:  absolute position with top, left 50% and translate is working wrong

```
<style>
        .img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Check example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/JRXxLB?editors=1100)**

CSS:

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] img {
  align-self: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My favorite vertical alignment hack:

```
.vertical-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

It uses `translateY` and `top` to sandwich an item into a container with unknown height. This requires IE10+.

Comment: In this case it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure that parent div of that image has height greater than image height.

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] img {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
                some text<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
            <div class="col-xs-6 different-height-1" style="border:1px solid green;">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 different-height-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You put min height, but I do not know event a min height. Your second image is not vertically aligned inside the row.

Comment: I tried to make it aligned middle with respect to col. but other answer solved it.. Just tried and edited mine with that..

Answer (score 0):

You have to go against bootstrap styling but than it works

```css
.img_container {
  position: relative;
}
.reset_pos {
  position: static !important;
}
.center {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid red;">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        some text
        <br />some text
        <br />some text
        <br />some text
        <br />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        some text
        <br />some text
        <br />some text
        <br />some text
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row img_container" style="border:1px solid red;">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 container reset_pos">
        <img class="img  center" src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but in this case a column with an image in not responsive.